# How to get an object in spring boot from REQUEST scope

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to get an object in Spring Boot from REQUEST scope in several classes (without forwarding to classes). Those. it is necessary in each class to have an actual object for the current request. If possible.

```
@Bean(name = "wp")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public WrapperRequest getWrapperRequest() {
    WrapperRequest wrapperRequest = new WrapperRequest();
    wrapperRequest.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    return wrapperRequest;
}
```

Comment: It's not unfortunately possible to autowire the **actual** object in all cases: it can be done only if components that need your `WrapperRequest` are themselves in `request` scope. If those components are, for example, in `singleton` scope, then what's autowired will be a proxy, and if there's no active request going on, then attempting to call any methods on said proxy will result in exception.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov : how can this be solved ?

Comment: @serv-inc, what do you mean be "solved"? There's not going to be any request-scoped objects outside of the active request scope. And inside the request scope, it's no different in autowiring them compared to singleton objects. Singleton-scoped component can have a proxy of request-scoped component autowired in it, but outside of active request, any call to a proxy will throw exception. I already commented about it previously.

Answer (score 1):

You can `@Autowired` it in a class under spring context ( For example class with `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository` annotation)

Example:

```
@Autowired
private WrapperRequest wp;
```